# Good CLI tool to edit mp4 metadata?

Tags: server

Is there any tool for headless CLI usage to edit mp4 metadata, preferably without remuxing?

I need to edit metadata like, audio/subtitle language tags.

Comment: handbrake could do it I think.

Answer (score 3):

You are after the command line application atomicparsley:

```
sudo apt-get install atomicparsley
```

You can see the available options with:

```
andrew@ilium~$ AtomicParsley -h

AtomicParlsey sets metadata into MPEG-4 files & derivatives supporting 3 tag
 schemes: iTunes-style, 3GPP assets & ISO defined copyright notifications.

AtomicParlsey quick help for setting iTunes-style metadata into MPEG-4 files.

General usage examples:
  AtomicParsley /path/to.mp4 -T 1
  AtomicParsley /path/to.mp4 -t +
  AtomicParsley /path/to.mp4 --artist "Me" --artwork /path/to/art.jpg
  Atomicparsley /path/to.mp4 --albumArtist "You" --podcastFlag true
  Atomicparsley /path/to.mp4 --stik "TV Show" --advisory explicit

Getting information about the file & tags:
  -T  --test        Test file for mpeg4-ishness & print atom tree
  -t  --textdata    Prints tags embedded within the file
  -E  --extractPix  Extracts pix to the same folder as the mpeg-4 file

Setting iTunes-style metadata tags
  --artist       (string)     Set the artist tag
  --title        (string)     Set the title tag
  --album        (string)     Set the album tag
  --genre        (string)     Genre tag (see --longhelp for more info)
  --tracknum     (num)[/tot]  Track number (or track number/total tracks)
  --disk         (num)[/tot]  Disk number (or disk number/total disks)
  --comment      (string)     Set the comment tag
  --year         (num|UTC)    Year tag (see --longhelp for "Release Date")
  --lyrics       (string)     Set lyrics (not subject to 256 byte limit)
  --lyricsFile   (/path)      Set lyrics to the content of a file
  --composer     (string)     Set the composer tag
  --copyright    (string)     Set the copyright tag
  --grouping     (string)     Set the grouping tag
  --artwork      (/path)      Set a piece of artwork (jpeg or png only)
  --bpm          (number)     Set the tempo/bpm
  --albumArtist  (string)     Set the album artist tag
  --compilation  (boolean)    Set the compilation flag (true or false)
  --hdvideo      (boolean)    Set the hdvideo flag (true or false)
  --advisory     (string*)    Content advisory (*values: 'clean', 'explicit')
  --stik         (string*)    Sets the iTunes "stik" atom (see --longhelp)
  --description  (string)     Set the description tag
  --longdesc     (string)     Set the long description tag
  --storedesc    (string)     Set the store description tag
  --TVNetwork    (string)     Set the TV Network name
  --TVShowName   (string)     Set the TV Show name
  --TVEpisode    (string)     Set the TV episode/production code
  --TVSeasonNum  (number)     Set the TV Season number
  --TVEpisodeNum (number)     Set the TV Episode number
  --podcastFlag  (boolean)    Set the podcast flag (true or false)
  --category     (string)     Sets the podcast category
  --keyword      (string)     Sets the podcast keyword
  --podcastURL   (URL)        Set the podcast feed URL
  --podcastGUID  (URL)        Set the episode's URL tag
  --purchaseDate (UTC)        Set time of purchase
  --encodingTool (string)     Set the name of the encoder
  --encodedBy    (string)     Set the name of the Person/company who encoded the file
  --apID         (string)     Set the Account Name
  --cnID         (number)     Set the iTunes Catalog ID (see --longhelp)
  --geID         (number)     Set the iTunes Genre ID (see --longhelp)
  --xID          (string)     Set the vendor-supplied iTunes xID (see --longhelp)
  --gapless      (boolean)    Set the gapless playback flag
  --contentRating (string*)   Set tv/mpaa rating (see -rDNS-help)

Deleting tags
  Set the value to "":        --artist "" --stik "" --bpm ""
  To delete (all) artwork:    --artwork REMOVE_ALL
  manually removal:           --manualAtomRemove "moov.udta.meta.ilst.ATOM"

More detailed iTunes help is available with AtomicParsley --longhelp
Setting reverse DNS forms for iTunes files: see --reverseDNS-help
Setting 3gp assets into 3GPP & derivative files: see --3gp-help
Setting copyright notices for all files: see --ISO-help
For file-level options & padding info: see --file-help
Setting custom private tag extensions: see --uuid-help
Setting ID3 tags onto mpeg-4 files: see --ID3-help

----------------------------------------------------------------------
AtomicParsley version: 0.9.6 (utf8)

Report issues at http://bitbucket.org/wez/atomicparsley/issues/new/
andrew@ilium~$
```

There is an undocumented `--overWrite` tag which will allow you to edit your files 'in place' as well...

Comment: This command gives a strange output with ubuntu 18.04... ```The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgpac-dev:i386 : Depends: gpac:i386 but it is not going to be installed
```

Comment: @Freedo Hmmm... could be a local issue I suspect, perhaps try: `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: Ok, I installed it but: `-bash: atomicparsley: command not found
`

Comment: @Freedo Ahhh.... I shall add to my answer: the command to run is actually `AtomicParsley` Case specific command.

Comment: looking at it help output it doesn't seem to support editing the language tag of audio/subtitle tracks.

Comment: @Freedo Have a look at `AtomicParsley --longhelp`, there is some info at the end of this about setting language options but I confess that I have not used these options...